# What do enemies mean when they shout 'plough the lily'?

Tags: the-witcher-2

In the prologue I hear a good many enemy soldiers shout this refrain as they charge at me. I presume when they say 'plough' they don't mean it in the agrarian sense, but I think I'm missing some cultural context here because I don't quite understand how Geralt is 'the lily'.

What exactly do my enemies mean when they scream 'plough the lily'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lily refers to Temeria in this case. At the beginning of the Witcher 2 you're fighting for Temeria. The emblem for Temeria are [silver lilies on black background](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Temeria):

[image]

Ploughing does refer to what you're suspecting, "plough the lily" means pretty much "fuck Temeria".

The Witcher Wiki also explains this particular phrase in the trivia section:

> The term "Lilies" is used as a collective noun, likely meant to be
>   derogatory, referring to the people from Temeria. A common phrase used
>   by non-Temerian NPC enemies in The Witcher 2 is, "Plough the lilies!"
>   The term most likely originates from the silver lilies in Temeria's
>   emblem.

Comment: After reading about the lilies on the emblem, I would translate "plough the lily" as "kill the lily(person behind the emblem)", but I like your definition better.

Comment: Yeah, "plough" as in "plough down".

Comment: @DoubleDouble That verb is used often enough in all the Witcher games that I'm very certain my interpetation is accurate